# Where is the delete repository button?

Tags: plasticscm

Logging into plastic scm I don't see a way to delete my repository, am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: https://www.plasticscm.com/support

Comment: Reason why I get a negative?

Answer (score 0):

In the Plastic GUI (repositories list) you can right-click on a repository and delete it.

You can also use the `cm repository delete --help` command.

Comment: Just to be clear. There is no right-click in the repository list where the OP is. That just brings up the default web browser context menu. You need to install the app to do this. https://www.plasticscm.com/download